# Should i use Promise to solve this task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm requesting items from the site and i need to check if description of the subject has word "purchsed" in it and only then save it to DB.

So, when i do something liek this:

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
  if(!isPurchased)
    saveToDb(item)
}
```

But it is not working (item is saved in any case), because function provided in IF statement (isPurchased) returning undefined (because of async node behavior, i think).

So, i wrote Promise notPurchased :

```
function notPurchased(advert) {
  return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject) {
        if (description.length == 0)
          resolve();

        return request('adverts', {'count' : 50},  function(resp) {

          for (i = 0; i < resp.count; i++) {

            if(resp.response.items[i].text.match('purchased') != null)
              reject('This item has been purchased!');
          }

          resolve();
        });
      });
}
```

And then using this promise in forEach loop:

```
response.items.forEach(function(item) {
   notPurchased(item).then(function() {
     DB.storeItem(item);
   });
});
```

Is this a good aproach? I don't have enough experience with NodeJS and it seems to me a little tricky to define a promise for simple bool function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you can do is to loop to look for what items are not in db, and then, insert all of them with `Promise.all`.
Would be like this:

```
const itemsNotSaved = items.filter((item) => {
       //Check if item is in db already.
       //If it is, return false, if not, true
});

const itemsPromises = itemsNotSaved.map((item) => {
  //Create a new promise for inserting item
});

//Execute every Promise
Promise.all(itemsPromises)
.then((items) => {
 //No errors, items have been inserted in the database
})
.catch((error) => {
 //console.log(error);
})
```